# Ionic tabs within page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, upgrade, ionic6

I have an Ionic 3 Angular app that I'm trying to upgrade to Ionic 6.
The app itself is not tabbed, but there are pages within it that have tabs.

A simplified example:

`foo.html`:

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- insert header here -->
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="guide">
        <ion-icon md="map-sharp" ios="map"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Guide</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="scan">
        <ion-icon name="barcode-sharp"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Scan</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

The problem is how to arrange it so that upon opening `foo`, the `foo` page loads, containing the `guide` page, and switching between tabs of the `foo` page doesn't unload that page.

(I'm not having trouble getting `foo` to set the tab to `guide`; the issue is getting the router to work properly.)

Things I've tried and why they didn't work:

- Using `UrlHandlingStrategy` to only look at the last component; caused the `foo` page to be replaced entirely by the `guide` page and the header and tab bar were gone.
- Having `foo/guide` route to `GuidePage`; `guide.html` contains `ion-virtual-scroll` elements and it complains of a `ChunkLoadError` because it tried to load the chunk from `/foo/[snip]ion-virtual-scroll[snip].js`. Also, that might have failed for the same reason as above.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: NoLongerBreathedIn, just to recap and make sure
You are :
1. Trying to load a page where there is multiple tabs and select the default one ( like guide ? )
2. Able to switch between the tabs while keeping the main page ( parent of tabs ) loaded
If this is correct, 
There is multiple approaches to this, I'll give some examples, but top of my head would be : 
- Use query params to handle the active tab and have a unique route
- Use a second router within the page to handle navigation inside the page

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation#child-routes-within-tabs
I think you are trying to do something similar to this

Comment: I'll give that a go. Could you write that down as an answer if you want the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple approaches to
this, I'll give some examples, but top of my head would be :

- Use
  query params to handle the active tab and have a unique route
- Use
  a second router within the page to handle navigation inside the
  page

This is similar to what you are trying to achieve https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation#child-routes-within-tabs, which seems to be actually similar, using child routes

Let me know and I can do a quick example in case in stackblitz if you are struggling, or if that didn't work for you

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm not feeling too good today. If the bounty expires before I have a chance to test it, and it works, I'll make a new bounty and give it to you.

Comment: No worries, bounty or not, let me just know if this was helpful, otherwise can help more :D

Comment: I tried "nested routes", which didn't work (all the content tried to scroll, including the pages that should have been hidden, and the tab bar).

Child routes would be slightly more difficult, due to having arranged things in a different way (fixable, but tedious). I'll try that in a bit.

Comment: Tried nested routes with `ion-tabs` not nested in `ion-content`; this didn't quite work either, the content simply remained invisible. Weird.

Comment: Well, I think I know why the content remained invisible. That ChunkLoadError still happened. ????

Comment: Are you loading correctly the routes, do you have a little stackblitz or something reproducable ? I could help you there this way

Comment: The problem was with Webpack. Upgrading to Angular 14 fixed it.